# Using Data-binding expressions in HyperLinkField

Tags: c#, asp.net

I dont have clear how to use Data-binding expressions correctly, I would like show/hide a column based on data from the table.

for example:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Insert_Inventario.aspx?ID={0}" 
Visible='<%= toogleInventario(Eval("Id")) %>' DataTextFormatString="{0}" NavigateUrl="~/Insert_Inventario.aspx"
                                Target="_top" Text="Inventario" />
```

In code behind :

```
 public string toogleInventario(string strID)
    {
        //do stuff
        return "True";
    }
```

but i get the error :

> "Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event."

I know i can use the RowDataBound event for fix this, but i would like a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:HyperLinkField id="hlf1" runat="server" />
```

In Code-behind:

```
    if (shouldRemoveColumn) 
    {
        gv1.Columns.Remove(hlf1);
    }
```